# Extracting float numbers from the filename

Tags: sed, filenames

I have a series of files with names which are of form

> path/A_b#_c#_d#_e#.out

where "#" stands for float numbers. How can I extract all of these numbers from the filename, most likely, with the help of sed?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the **actual** filenames.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want each number separated by a space or by a newline?

Comment: Well, the filename is for example " ./Folder1/A_b0.5_c0.654_d0.157_e1.6.out". I want each of them to be extracted individually as I should later employ them to  produce a new filename.

Comment: Do the letters appear literally and always go from "b" to "e"?

Comment: The letters of A, b,c,d,e are always fixed, but not necessarily in alphabetic order. My filenames are in principle two types of names, with the same pattern as I have mentioned in the question, where the letters of "A,b,c,d,e" have been employed in one type and the other type consists of "G,u,w,g,b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:
`sed -E 's/[A-Za-z_]/ /g;s/. {1,}$//;s/^ {1,}([0-9])/\1/'`

Example:

```
echo "A_b0.5_c0.654_d0.157_e1.6.out" | sed -E 's/[A-Za-z_]/ /g;s/. {1,}$//;s/^ {1,}([0-9])/\1/'
0.5  0.654  0.157  1.6
```

Someone with higher `sed` skills might produce a better one.

Comment: Thank you. That is precisely what I was looking for. I only add "|awk '{print $4 }' " at the end of the sed line to extract for instance the fourth number.

Comment: Finding the 4th number is much more easy with `grep -oP '(?<=_[a-z])[0-9.]+(?=.out)' `